# reference dynamic libraries using relative path in CMakeLists

Tags: c++, c, cmake, dll

I have a project using some dynamic libraries. The generated executable runs well on my local machine. However, if I share it with others, the executable will still try to find dynamic libraries with the **absolute** path in my local machine, which of course do not exist in other machines. How can I resolve this issue by changing CMakeLists?

My current CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(MyProject)
link_directories("libs/mac_arm64")
add_executable(MyProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyProject expat bz2 z geos_c)
```

Comment: Don't spam language tags. If you use C++, tag only C++. C is a completely different programming language.

Comment: try `find_library`

Comment: You can use `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` or `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`.

Answer (score 0):

When CMake builds libraries and executables, it (by default) embeds **absolute** RPATH into them. This allows to successfully find all libraries when run those executables on the build machine.

But those libraries and executables, which are created in the **build tree**, are not intended to be copied to other machine.

Instead, you should **install** those libraries and executables. Upon installation CMake strips their hardcoded RPATHs, which allows to distribute them.

Add to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
install(TARGETS MyProject DESTINATION bin/)
```

and build it with

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install
make
make install
```

This will install your project into `install` directory near the `build`. After installation you could pack content of `install` directory and send it to your customers/friends/whoever. CMake even provides [cpack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cpack.1.html) tool for easy packaging an installed project.

More about RPATH settings in CMake can be found in their [wiki](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling).